# CSS variating height problem with IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-position

I have problem positioning left sidebar (variating height DIV) ON IE6.

Main needs:
1. I cant set height value, cause height is variating and should be computed by browser.
2. Sidebar must have top and bottom spacings.

Top bar issue is solved by replacing position to relative.

Any ideas ? Thank you in advance !

Below you can see simplified code and snapshot how it looks on standard browsers.

```
.container {
    left: 550px; 
    top: 10px; 
    width: 196px; 
    position: absolute; 
    line-height: 0px; 
    font-size: 1px;
}
.inner {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 114px; 
    background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
}
.leftbar {
    left: 0px; 
    top: 7px; 
    bottom: 7px; 
    width: 4px; 
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(111, 111, 111); 
}
.topbar {
    left: 7px; 
    top: 0px; 
    right: 7px; 
    height: 4px; 
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(111, 111, 111); 
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="leftbar"></div>
    <div class="topbar"></div>
</div>
```

[LINK TO SCREEN SHOT IMAGE](http://www.speedyshare.com/631899164.html)

Comment: Why do people insist on continuing to use IE6?

Comment: Word. The sooner it goes, the better... and the more people who drop IE 6 support, the easier for everyone else.

Comment: If only it were that easy to drop IE6. An average of different sites (mine...) shows that 17% of the total number of visitors is using IE6. That´s a lot of people. And not just my client´s clients, I have several clients who are stuck with IE6 as well and they want to see what they pay for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 is tremendously bad when it comes to absolute positioning. Positioning something at the same time from left and right or from top and bottom just doesn't work.

You basically have four options:

1. Drop support for IE6.
2. Give up on absolute positioning and use some other method (floats for example).
3. Provide dumbed down version of the site for IE6 - for example overriding some styles using conditional comments.
4. Use JavaScript to aid IE6 in positioning (for example [absolutefudge.js](http://www.nixsoft.co.uk/index.php?file=/articles/absolute-fudge.page)).